# Alternative for ui.bootstrap progress bars

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I wanted to use multiple progress bars in my project to show data, but I realized that I need sometimes 100-200 bars. I guess it's not good to use progress bars from ui.bootstrap to do this.

[image]
In my case, one progress bar is a view of one month for ONE user, multiply it by 12 (year view) and by number of users.
One bar has ~31 cols (days of month), and I change color of days by specific property.

Is any alternative to show this data?

Comment: You might wanna specify whether you are working with Bootstrap 4 or Bootstrap 3. That's kinda important because those 2 versions are completely incompatible with each other...

Comment: I'ts Bootstrap 3, I will try in this way, which I described, we will see